# Load image from sharedPreferences to pdf in Flutter

Tags: image, flutter, pdf, sharedpreferences

I'm need to load a image from sharedPreferences to a pdf document.
The image loads normally when in normal use, but i don't know how to make it load in the pdf.
When I try to load it like a normal image I get "Unhandled Exception: type 'Image' is not a subtype of type 'PdfImage'"

This is how I use it normally.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_settings_screens/flutter_settings_screens.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:MyApp/SharedPrefUtility.dart';

Future<void> initSettings() async {
  await Settings.init(
    cacheProvider: SharePreferenceCache(),
  );
}

class ProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ProfilePageState createState() => _ProfilePageState();
}

class _ProfilePageState extends State<ProfilePage> {
  Image logo;

  pickImage(ImageSource source) async {
    final _image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

    if (_image != null) {
      setState(() {
        logo = Image.file(_image);
      });
      ImageSharedPrefs.saveImageToPrefs(
          ImageSharedPrefs.base64String(_image.readAsBytesSync()));
    } else {
      print('Error picking image!');
    }
  }

  loadImageFromPrefs() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final imageKeyValue = prefs.getString(IMAGE_KEY);
    if (imageKeyValue != null) {
      final imageString = await ImageSharedPrefs.loadImageFromPrefs();
      setState(() {
        logo = ImageSharedPrefs.imageFrom64BaseString(imageString);
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadImageFromPrefs();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        title: Text('Profile Settings'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                ClipRect(
                  child: Container(
                    width: 300,
                    height: 300,
                    child: logo == null ? Text('No image selected.') : logo,
                  ),
                ),
                RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    pickImage(ImageSource.gallery);
                  },
                  child: Text('Pick Company Logo'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

With SharedPrefUtility.dart

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

const IMAGE_KEY = 'IMAGE_KEY';

class ImageSharedPrefs {
  static Future<bool> saveImageToPrefs(String value) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    return await prefs.setString(IMAGE_KEY, value);
  }


  static Future<String> loadImageFromPrefs() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return prefs.getString(IMAGE_KEY);
  }

  static String base64String(Uint8List data) {
    return base64Encode(data);
  }

  static imageFrom64BaseString(String base64String) {
    return Image.memory(
      base64Decode(base64String),
      fit: BoxFit.contain,
    );
  }
}
```

Any Suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

davey06 gave the answer on gitHub

```
   final imageString = await ImageSharedPrefs.loadImageFromPrefs(); 
// Create a PDF document.
final document = pw.Document();

// Add page to the PDF
document.addPage(pw.Page(build: (context) {
  return pw.Center(
    child: pw.Image(
      PdfImage.file(document.document, bytes: base64Decode(imageString)),
    ),
  );
}));

// Return the PDF file content
return document.save();
```

https://github.com/DavBfr/dart_pdf/issues/477

Comment: You should mark your own answer as the right one, so it doesn't show up as unanswered to the others

Answer (score 0):

*"Unhandled Exception: type 'Image' is not a subtype of type 'PdfImage'"* - it says you need to convert **Image** to **PdfImage**

```
import 'package:pdf/pdf.dart';
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart ' as pw;

pdf = pw.Document();
PdfImage pdfImage = PdfImage.fromImage(pdf.document, image: logo);

pdf.addPage(
  pw.Page(
    pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
    build: (context) {
      return pw.Image(arcPdfImage, fit: pw.BoxFit.contain);
    },
  ),
);
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the quick reply. I still can't get it to work. I have a working pdf already with images from the assets folder and from the chache and everything works 100%. I just need to load the image from the sharedPreferences also.  I was thinking it should be something like   final logo = ImageSharedPrefs.imageFrom64BaseString(await ImageSharedPrefs.loadImageFromPrefs());   But i get the said error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using images taken from my assets to create PDF in this way:

```
PdfImage _logo = PdfImage.file(
    doc.document,
    bytes: (await rootBundle.load('assets/client-logo.png')).buffer.asUint8List(),
  );

//later, during widget tree creation 
pw.Image(_logo, width: 180);
```

It's not exactly what you're doing, but I think it's close enough. The PdfImage class can take as input any Uint8List for the `bytes` argument, so you should be able to use the same input you're using for the `base64String` method you defined for `ImageSharedPrefs`

Comment: Hi.Thanks.  I do use that for the images from my assets folder, I also load an image from the cache. Every thing works fine, except the image from the shared Preferences. rootBundle can only be used for images that exist before the app is launched so to speak. The image that is in shared preferences is in string format, so im trying to convert it so that the pdf can read it.

Comment: @Fenix have you tried to show the image from preferences in a standard Flutter widget, like `Image`? If you can manage that, let's say, by using the named constructor `Image.memory()` which takes as input a Uint8List, you should be able to use the same input for `PdfImage`

Comment: Hi. Yes, I'm trying to do that, but no results yet. I'm sure there must be a way to do it, i just haven't found it yet.